# Related to goals in maven plugin

Tags: maven-plugin

I have designed a maven plugin which has two goals.However, I want to attach one of it as a preGoal to another i.e; everytime the second goal runs it should be preceeded by the first one automatically.Can anyone tell how to do it?

Comment: what have you done so far would have really helped here.

Comment: I have written a maven plugin which has two goals working independently.For ex- plugin name- xyz has goal a and b which work when following commands are executed: mvn xyz:a and mvn xyz:b. However, I want a to always run whenever b is executed. Prehook it basically.

Answer (score 0):

Referring the [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) under **A Build Phase is Made Up of Plugin Goals**

> Note: In Maven 2.0.5 and above, multiple goals bound to a phase are
>   ***executed in the same order as they are declared in the POM***, however
>   multiple instances of the same plugin are not supported. Multiple
>   instances of the same plugin are grouped to execute together and
>   ordered in Maven 2.0.11 and above

So, if you put `Goal-A` before `Goal-B` in your POM and bind these to the same phase of life-cycle. Then `Goal-B` would always be preceded by `Goal-A`.

Comment: Thanks,but i dont want to run it as part of any project. when i execute mvn xyz:b command I want the goal a to be executed first automatically. Can I declare it in the pom of the plugin itself?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html                                                                               The command @Execute("goal name") helped.